# Applying conditional CSS selectors to magento atrribute

Tags: css, magento, css-selectors

I am trying to do the following:

I have set up a number of Magento attributes for my products & I want to display an icon next to an attribute  called "Color" as well as attach an alt tag to this icon/image. My theme has each of the attributes set up as a dt tag, & so the css I am trying to apply is as follows:

```
dt[foo^="Color:"]{background: url(http://xyz.com/skin/frontend/default/default/images/warning.png) no-repeat 100% 0%;}
```

and here is the markup:
    ``` <div class="white-box-inner">' '<dl class="attribute-list clearfix">``<dt class="first">Size:</dt>``<dd class="first">21</dd> ``` ``` <dt>Manufacturer:</dt>``<dd>Hat Designs</dd>``<dt>Color:</dt> ```
``` <dd>Red</dd>``<dt>Fabric</dt> ``` `<dd>Felt</dd> </dl>` `</div>`

- This however does not display the icon I'd like to appear.
- I'm also not sure how to have an alt tag associated with this icon either via css. I'd rather not mess with the template files. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.
-TM

Comment: You cannot associate alt text or a title using CSS. We'll need to see your markup in order to determine the selector to use.

Comment: @BoltClock thanks, here's the markup for the containing div:
<div class="white-box-inner">
<dl class="attribute-list clearfix">
<dt class="first">Size:</dt>
<dd class="first">21</dd>
<dt>Manufacturer:</dt>
<dd>Hat Designs</dd>
<dt>Color:</dt>
<dd>Red</dd>
<dt>Fabric</dt>
<dd>Felt</dd>
</dl>
</div>

Comment: You'll want to edit that into your question, as code isn't formatted in comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your markup it looks like you're trying to select an element by its content. Attribute selectors only select by attributes; they don't select by content.

There was going to be a `:contains()` pseudo-class, but it was dropped from the spec and so you can't do this using CSS selectors anymore.

[jQuery implements `:contains()`](http://api.jquery.com/contains-selector), though, so you could simply use jQuery to add a class and style that class.

Additionally, you cannot associate alt text or a tooltip to a background image in CSS. You're going to have to go through the JavaScript route to achieve this.